# How to send a task item in Outlook using SMTP in Asp.Net? Is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, outlook, vcalendar

I have been searching from few days to find that How can I send a task item in outlook using SMTP in asp.net? but I am unable to find any concrete solution.

Kindly help me. I dont want to use any interop or dll, I just want to use SMTP and send a task item like we can send a meeting request using .ics/vcs/ical.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

All the samples I can find are using the Outlook Interop. You need to find the format of the task message so you can embed that into a normal SMTP message. I don't know whether Microsoft publish the details, but you could try sending one from Outlook and looking at the raw data of the message you receive.

Comment: Kindly if you like my answer accept it and up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate Outlook, you need to use the Outlook Object Model - but that can't be done in a web application.  If you need to run server side code to work with Exchange, you need to use Exchange Web Services.